# Subscribe methods for channels in Redis in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stackexchange.redis

I try to use StackExchange.Redis as a message broker. It works fine, but I have one disadvantage now. I need MQ for communicate 2 ASP.NET Core projects. 
`ConnectionMultiplexer` has a `Subscriber` method which subscribe same Action delegate to the MQ. Is there any way not to do this through `Startup` class?

Firstly, I tried to realize this with the help of attribute class, code like

```
public class FireAndForgetAttribute<T> : Attribute
{
    public FireAndForgetAttribute(IConnectionMultiplexer plexer, string channelName, Action<T> reaction)
    {
            var subscriber = plexer.GetSubscriber();

            subscriber.Subscribe(channelName, (channel, message) => 
            {
                var data = JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>(message);

                reaction.Invoke(data);
            }, flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
    }
}
```

but it's not a good way, because there are still no generic attributes in C# (just in roadmap marked as discussed, nothing else), and also I cannot pass `Action<T>` of a concrete object here.

P.P.S. Sorry, I've forgot to change head of my question. Now it's correct.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to configure it in the `Startupt` class? it's a one time configuration, isn't it?

You can configure a Service in which the plexer is injected via constructor and subscribe there to your implementation....

Comment: @jjchiw, because I want to have an instrument to easy subscribing objects. If I would to pass `Action<T>` to the `Attribute` constructor, I could use Scutor for autosubscribing, and easy way to develop a service marked classes I need to be subscribed for different channels by attribute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this, it was a long time ago, using Nancy, EasyQ and DryIOC

It's not based on attributes but classes

Helper method that will register all the concrete clases of `IPipeline`

```
RegisterMultipleTypesToContainer(container, typeof(IPipeline));
```

I suppose this is what Scutor does, but there was no scutor at the time so have to use Reflection, and then just subscribe....

```
private void RegisterMultipleTypesToContainer(IContainer container, Type type)
{
  var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                         .Where(x => 
                               x.FullName.StartsWith("MyAssembly", StringComparison.Ordinal))SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes());

   var types = allTypes.Where(x => type.IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract).ToList();

            foreach (var concreteTypes in types)
            {
                var genericTypes = concreteTypes.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x != type).ToList();
                foreach (var genericType in genericTypes)
                {
                    container.Register(genericType, concreteTypes, Reuse.Singleton);
                    var pipeline = container.Resolve(genericType) as IPipeline;
                    pipeline.Subscribe();
                }
            }
        }
```

```
 public class HelloPipeline :
        BasePipeline<HelloPipeline.Message>
    {
    IBusService _bus;
    HelloPipeline(IBusService bus){
     _bus = bus;
     }
    private Task ExecuteAsync(String channel, ) { }
       public void Subscribe()
        {
            _bus.SubscribeAsync<T>(this.GetType().Name, this.ExecuteAsync);
        }
    }
```

Just checked old code but still works, hope it gives you an idea, but I thinks what you are trying to achieve is the same as I did, but with other tools

Comment: Thanks! That's enough for my task!